# Updating an event in Microsoft Graph in Node

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a mobile application that gains access to user's calendar (Microsoft). Once I get the access token, I save it in my backend database for reuse. I then - separately - call the Microsoft Graph API from node.js API with the saved token which works fine :

```
var microsoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
var client = microsoftGraph.Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) => {
        done(null, token);
    }
});

client.api('/me/calendar/events/xyz').patch({
    'Body': {
        'ContentType': '0',
        'Content': 'test from api 2'
    }
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('res: ', res);
    }
});
```

The problem is the token expires and it doesn't come with refresh token to renew it from server without user intervention.

Here is the error I get after ~2 hours:

```
err: {
    statusCode: 401,
    code: 'InvalidAuthenticationToken',
    message: 'CompactToken validation failed with reason code: -2147184088.',
    requestId: '5bdd2402-b1b9-4c25-8b2d-1ca2c4a79192',
    date: 2017 - 08 - 07 T19: 27: 44.000 Z,
    body: {
        code: 'InvalidAuthenticationToken',
        message: 'CompactToken validation failed with reason code: -2147184088.',
        innerError: {
            'request-id': '5bdd2402-b1b9-4c25-8b2d-1ca2c4a79192',
            date: '2017-08-07T15:27:44'
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? There has to be a way to integrate a server side code with Microsoft Graph without the need to renew tokens from client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access tokens expire after 60 minutes, so you'll either need to get a new one or use a refresh token.  Refresh tokens can be used to get a new access token and the docs for that API call are here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token

To get a refresh token, request the `offline_access` permission and the user will see this in the consent screen as "Access your data anytime".  An example of requesting the `offline_access` scope can be found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#2-get-authorization

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dan. My problem is I cannot ask for offline_access since I'm initiating the access request from mobile app. This means I either have to create a web page for token requests or put the app secret on the mobile app?

Comment: The specific error I get in Xamarin application is "API does not accept 'openid email profile offline_access' value as user-provided scopes"

Comment: I'm not an auth expert, but I think OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow would fit your situation better since you're using a mobile app and a backend.  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code . Basically users sign in on your phone app and instead of getting an access token back right away, you get a code that you send to your backend and it exchanges that code for tokens (access token and refresh tokens).  So the app secrets are only stored on the server and used when requesting tokens.

Comment: more info can be found here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-12#section-4.1